# Accessing Lua Functions On Other Files

Tags: lua

I want to separate my Lua file into two files: one that holds my functions and one that can call them. I have done a lot of research on this and all the resources I find do not explain this process very in depth. They typically say to use:

```
require "subsystem.lua"
```

I put this at the top of a new Lua file that is saved to the same directory and am not able to access anything.

Is there a config file I need to modify? Where is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Require the module

The [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) function looks in a series of places to find a module. The exact list of places can be extensively customized by adjusting fields in the global table `package`.

The easiest way to get a sense of how many places and names it uses when looking for a module is to look at the error message produced when `require` fails. For example, on my PC, Lua 5.1 says this:

```
C:\Users\Ross>lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "xyzzy"
stdin:1: module 'xyzzy' not found:
        no field package.preload['xyzzy']
        no file '.\xyzzy.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\xyzzy.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\xyzzy\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\xyzzy.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\xyzzy\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\xyzzy.luac'
        no file '.\xyzzy.dll'
        no file '.\xyzzy51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\xyzzy.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\xyzzy51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\xyzzy.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\xyzzy51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
>
```

After looking internally, the first "real" place it looks for `xyzzy` is in the file named `.\xyzzy.lua`. Then it tries a number of folders and names in the folder where `lua.exe` was found. Finally, it looks for a DLL that might offer it. The list of folders it searches for a `.lua` file is controlled by the string value in `package.path`. (The comparable list for DLLs in is `package.cpath`.) In that value, `require` will replace each `?` with the module name, and then attempt to read the file. The first one to succeed is used.

(The story here is slightly more complicated; you can create "searchers" that `require` will use to look in different places, and even change the order of the built-in searchers, but that is an advanced topic.)

So just putting modules in Lua files in the current directory should work just fine, and adjusting `package.path` before calling `require` for your own modules can cover most quirks you will encounter.

## Create a module to require

At its simplest, a module is just something that can be stored in `package.loaded`. Which is what `require` will do with it once it has been found, so that multiple calls to `require` will only search once and always return the same value.

The traditional answer is for that "something" to be a table, usually mostly populated by functions that can be called, and occasionally having values. The `math` module is a good example: it provides lots of functions like `sin` and `cos`, along with the useful value `math.pi` and `math.huge`.

Aside from being stored in a table, there is nothing special about a function in a module. Like any other function, it takes parameters and return zero or more values. The only real rule is that a module should not change or add global variables.

So a very minimal module file can be as simple as:

```
return { 
  addtwo = function(a, b) return a+b end,
  subtwo = function(x) return x-2 end,
}
```

which if stored as `example.lua` could be used like this:

```
local example = require "example"
print(example.addtwo(2,2)) -- 4
print(example.subtwo(42))  -- 40
```

## A better module skeleton

Sticking all your code in a single table declaration will not fly for most real cases. It does not scale well, and it makes it difficult to clearly express the relationship among functions that share state.

```
-- simple modules

-- capture the name searched for by require
local NAME=...

-- table for our functions
local M = { }

-- A typical local function that is also published in the 
-- module table. 
local function addtwo(a,b) return a+b end
M.addtwo = addtwo

-- Shorthand form is less typing and doesn't use a local variable
function M.subtwo(x) return x-2 end

return M
```

## Why no call to the module() function?

Lua 5.1 included a standard function named `module()` intended to be used at the top of module implementations. Its use was never required, and a consensus formed fairly quickly that it was not as helpful an idea as hoped. It has since been deprecated.

As a result, the simple skeleton I show above does not use it, and is portable to all versions of Lua since 5.1.

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is to return a table with the fields you want to access in `subsystem.lua` and then assign and use fields from that table in your main file. Something along these lines:

```
-- subsystem.lua

local function doSomething()
  -- do something useful here
end

local function doMore()
  -- do something else useful
end

return { doSomething = doSomething, doMore = doMore }

-- main.lua

local subsystem = require "subsystem" -- don't add `.lua` to your `require` call
subsystem.doSomething()
subsystem.doMore()
```

You may want to check [Modules tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) for details.

Comment: I was able to execute a function using this method. I was not able to return a value tho. I did have to put my substem.lua file into the defualt directory of my IDE tho.. How can I specify where to look and return a value?

Comment: Make sure you have `return my-result` statement in your function. If that doesn't help, post a question with details of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `dofile` instead of `require`.

`dofile` accepts file names, with paths.

`require` accepts module names and uses Lua search paths.

Comment: I like the idea of specifying where my file is because the location of the module has been confusing. Can you give me an example of calling a function on a separate file and getting a return value?

Comment: @OT2O, files run with `dofile` can create global functions or return them in table for instance. Local functions are just that and cannot be seen outside the file.