# How can I test functions inside a single file Lua script?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, lua

I would like to unit test functions from a single file Lua script, say `script.lua`. The script looks something like follows:

```
-- some fields from gvsp dissector which shall be post processed in custom dissector
gvsp_field0_f = Field.new("gvsp.<field0-name>")
gvsp_field1_f = Field.new("gvsp.<field1-name>")

-- custom protocol declaration
custom_protocol = Proto("custom","Custom Postdissector")

-- custom protocol field declarations
field0_f = ProtoField.string("custom.<field0-name>","Custom Field 0")
field1_f = ProtoField.string("custom.<field1-name>","Custom Field 1")

-- register custom protocol as postdissector
register_postdissector(custom_protocol)

function custom_protocol.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    -- local field values of "pre" dissector which are analyzed
    local gvsp_field0_value = gvsp_field0_f()
    local gvsp_field1_value = gvsp_field1_f()

    -- functions which shell be unit tested
    function0(...)
    function1(...)
end

function0(...)
    -- implementation
end

function1(...)
    -- implementation
end
```

Let's say I do not want to separate the functions from the script file into a separate module file (which would probably make things easier). How can I define tests (preferably with [luaunit](https://github.com/bluebird75/luaunit) because easy to integrate, but other tool would be ok as well) for the functions defined in `script.lua` inside the `script.lua` file or in a separate `test_script.lua` file?

Comment: That depends _a lot_ on _how_ you define things. Do you use `local` (that makes things considerably harder) or do you use "local `_ENV`ironments" (much easier)? How is your code structured? Please add a small code sample of how you define functions etc. (doesn't have to be the actual code, just dummy functions that match the way you're defining your stuff.) At present, there's just not enough information to give meaningful answers.

Comment: The script locks pretty like the post dissector from https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Dissectors#postdissectors with `local` functions defined at the end of the file which are used in the protocols `dissector` function. However I do not stick to this structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable separate script and unit test execution one needs at least 3 files (in this example 4 because the unit test framework `luaunit` which consists of a single file is integrated into the project directory). For this example all files reside in the same directory. The script `script.lua` may not define any functions in it but must import all functions it needs from its module `module.lua`.

```
-- script imports module functions
module = require('module')

-- ... and uses it to print the result of the addition function
result = module.addtwo(1,1)
print(result)
```

`module.lua` is implemented accoring to the [Lua module skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34646023/5308983) that its functions are automatically registered for import through other script files or modules.

```
-- capture the name searched for by require
local NAME=...

-- table for our functions
local M = { }

-- A typical local function that is also published in the
-- module table.
local function addtwo(a,b) return a+b end
M.addtwo = addtwo

-- Shorthand form is less typing and doesn't use a local variable
function M.subtwo(x) return x-2 end

return M
```

`test_module.lua` contains the unit tests for the module functions and imports `luaunit.lua` (unit test framework) for its execution. `test_module.lua` has the following content.

```
luaunit = require('luaunit')
script = require('module')

function testAddPositive()
    luaunit.assertEquals(module.addtwo(1,1),2)
end

os.exit( luaunit.LuaUnit.run() )
```

If you run the tests by executing `lua test_module.lua` the tests are executed separately from the script functionality.

```
.
Ran 1 tests in 0.000 seconds, 1 success, 0 failures
OK
```

The script is executed as usual with `lua script.lua` with output `2`.

Comment: I'm completely new to Lua and this approach `os.exit( luaunit.LuaUnit.run() )` was just what I needed. I kept facing "attempt to index a nil value (global 'LuaUnit')" when I followed the [UnitTesting guide](http://lua-users.org/wiki/UnitTesting) from lua-users.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: You can't!

I've asked the Lua team about this myself a few years ago as there is no obvious way for a script to know if it is the main script running or included (e.g., 'require'd).

There does not seem to be interest for adding such capability in the foreseeable future, either!

Comment: Ok. And what about implementing the tests in a separate `test_script.lua`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What about that?  Simply 'require' the file to test from your test file and call its public functions as needed.

Comment: In the example below the scripts main functionality is executed in addition to the unit tests. I do not want the scripts main functionality to be executed during unit test execution.

Comment: You need to organize your script accordingly, e.g., turn your script into some module.  Do not have any inline code inside it, just function/table definitions. For example, `local M={} ... function M.Init() ... return M` and then `my_module = require module` from your main file followed by `my_module.Init()` or something along those lines.

Comment: The rework of the example below works for me. I guess its similar to what you suggested...